# Can I use while to do nothing in php and if possible is it a good practice or not?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I was thinking of doing something like this in PHP

```
function doSomething() { /* ... */ }

while(my_array[] = doSomething()) { }
```

instead of using extra variable : `while(myValue = doSomething()) { myArray[] = myValue; }`

Is using while block to do nothing good practice or not? And if it is not - why?

Comment: I personally believe a `while` loop intended to do nothing is bad practice.

Comment: @dudelgrincen Yes, you can do it; when you say PHP does not accept the first syntax, what do you mean?

Comment: Works for me: `$x = array(); while($x[] = rand(0,3)) { } var_dump($x);`

Comment: also note that the two examples you've shown are different. The one without the extra variable will include the falsey value in the array whereas the other one won't

Comment: my fault ...it works :) Ive missed a parenthesis...its late here and maybe i should go to sleep ...Ill edit my qestion

Comment: +1 nick...however in my case it doesnt matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
$x = [];
while ($x[] = rand(0, 3)) { }
var_dump($x);

// array(4) {
//   [0]=>
//   int(4)
//   [1]=>
//   int(2)
//   [2]=>
//   int(2)
//   [3]=>
//   int(0)
// }
```

However, if you reevaluate the problem you're trying to solve, you may find that a different approach or construct may prove better, and won't require reducing the `while` construct to this purpose.

Comment: Has anyone noticed the `4` in my output?

Answer (score 9):

Technically the curly brackets are used to group multiple statements inside the `while` body. You do not even need them. E.g. the following is perfectly valid PHP code:

```
while ($my_array[] = doSomething());
                                   ^
```

As you can see, this uses a semicolon instead to terminate the statement (an empty one) of the `while` body. [Demo](http://eval.in/4787)

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot about that :)

Comment: Cool, but why ? Is it documented somewhere (I didn't find anything on php.net) ?

Comment: It's documented on http://php.net/while and http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php - a semicolon ends a statement (separates it from the next statement), curly braces allow you to create a statement that consists of multiple statements.

Comment: what does that `while(ob_end_clean());` mean?

Comment: @Hebe: It executes `ob_end_clean() ` in a loop until all output buffers are ended. There can be multiple, like a stack.